# Change color of selected days in calendar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar, jcalendar

I have the following jQuery calendar:

http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/

What I need is to select the days (eg 2 days), these are marked on the calendar by changing the background color (without having to hover over the calendar).

The idea is that this starts from the current day. If I choose 2 days, then check today and tomorrow.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Any idea?

Thank you,
Greetings.

Comment: do you want the current (clicked day) and its next day to be selected for example if 4 of december is clicked then 4 and 5 both?

Comment: Exactly. But that does not change color when placing the pointer over. The idea is to change the color of the cell only choose the amount of days. If I choose 3 days are 3 days from today. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry but i am still not getting what you want to do. Right now on hovering on any date on calender next consecutive 3 dates are highlighted with blue and when i click on the date at which the pointer at, the next 3 dates including the clicked one get highlighted with $1231 and class selected day is added. Do you want to stop this hovering effect and highlighting of consecutive 4 dates? and select only one date at time with the constraint that the date being clicked must have its very previous date highlighted or selected